# Redux state for particular component in a list

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning react and redux. I'm creating a todo app but I'm facing a issue. 
Let's say we have a list like

**List.js**

```
import React from 'react'

    function List() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ListItem>Text</ListItem>
                <ListItem>Text</ListItem>
                <ListItem>Text</ListItem>
                <ListItem>Text</ListItem>
            </div>
        )
    }



export default List
```

Then we have
**ListItem.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function ListItem() {
  //This is some local state
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);


  const loading = useSelector(state => state.loading);
  // This is the loading flag which is coming from the reducer.. Which will be either true or false


  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
  }, [loading]);
  //Whenever the loading flag from the reducer changes, it changes the local state


  return <div>{isLoading ? "loading" : "Hey, Im a list item"}</div>;
}

export default ListItem;
```

And let's say all `listItem` component have a click handler which `dispatch` an action to the change the loading flag in the reducer.
Now the **issue** I'm facing is as all the **listItem** are listening/subscribed to the same reducer, whenever the `isLoading` flag in the reducer changes, all the `listItem` start showing loading which is conditionally rendered from the `return` statement as shown above.
**Expected Behaviour** (or intended behaviour I must say)
I want to show **loading** on only that element that was clicked and whose local state was changed. But unfortunately my logic has a flaw that it all elements local states changes when the `isLoading` flag in the reducer changes

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is provide a key to each list item and assign loading to it in your reducer like this:

```
loading: {
   List1: isLoading, 
   List2: notLoading
}
```

Comment: Nice idea... but is that the only way to do it or is there something else we can try? Like an official way or something?

Comment: Well  you are using reducer that will make it global so, there is now way to do that or move your state from reducer to component that will handle their state on their own. Hope that makes sense.